# FiverrScript 404 error when visiting any page

Tags: php, mysql, http-status-code-404

I am using Fiverrscript v4.2 .
I have installed it on my website in public_html and it worked great as the config.php file was

```
$config['basedir']     =  '/home/username/public_html/';
$config['baseurl']     =  'http://example.com/';
```

after that I have installed a test version on a directory in my website and made the config.php file :

```
$config['basedir']     =  '/home/username/public_html/home';
$config['baseurl']     =  'http://example.com/home';
```

Now when ever I visit any page on my website ( example : www.example.com/signup it show me a 404 error however the homepage is working great .

Can you help me please , thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , I am just posting the answer because someone may need it .

The problem wasn't with PHP .
it was with the .htaccess file 
there is a line called `RewriteBase /`
Just change this line with your directory example `RewriteBase /directory`